# Notifications arrive when the app is opened, but not in the background

Tags: 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I don't know if it's the right place to ask my question, if not, sorry.

1st, I was using Sony Xperia Z5 premium for the last three years, never faced any issues but few days ago, I switched to Samsung galaxy s10+ and the problem I'm facing is, I'm not getting notifications from WhatsApp or some other apps when they're not opened.
When I open them, I got couple of notifications. 
If I don't open that app for whole day, and at night when I open it, I get notifications of all day.

Please guide which settings or options I should see?

Comment: Check battery optimization, battery saver, battery manager, aggressive battery, background data restriction, power saving mode or any other performance boosting settings. Uninstall RAM boosters, cleaners, background app killers and anti-virus tools (if any). Try clearing cache of affected apps and of Google Play Services / Framework for push notifications fix. See Play Services (and possibly your required app) in the list of Running Services from Developer Options. Or at extreme try disabling doze mode: `dumpsys deviceidle disable all`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the reply. I've tried battery optimization but nothing helped. Battery saver is also not on. I use wifi so background data doesn't effect. I've no performance boosting apps or ram cleaners etc. I'm getting notifications on other apps so push services is also working.

Comment: And you don's have Battery Manager / Adaptive Battery feature either? https://www.androidcentral.com/android-p-features-we-love-adaptive-battery-support

Comment: No sir, that's what I'm tired of, I've tried everything that came in my mind.