# Why do notifications stop for WhatsApp after few minutes?

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger, 9.0-pie, nokia-5

I have Nokia 5.1 Plus with Android Pie.

Now, since a few days, I'm facing this irritating problem. When the WhatsApp is open, it works fine. You receive push notifications, and messages are not delayed.

When you minimize it (i.e., open other apps) and leave the phone away, I don't notice any problem for 10-15 minutes. Even when screen is locked, I receive WhatsApp notifications.

After 10-15 minutes, WhatsApp kind of freezes. When I try to send message from other phones to my phone, I see nothing. When I use phone and open WhatsApp (which wasn't closed, just minimized), I see it takes 2-3 seconds to fetch pending messages. So it kind of stops.

I have removed all battery optimizations settings for this app. Did reset of the app, still can't solve this issue. How can I fix it?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213949/218526

Comment: I don't see it a duplicate. My notifications stop after a few minutes, not immediately.

Comment: But the reasons are same. Some power-saving / data-saving mechanism kills the apps in background.

Comment: I noticed something today after a month of problem. My phone has 32 GB memory. I noticed it had consumed 29 GB of it till today. So I freed up some space (9 GB free now). Later I noticed the WhatsApp problem is solved (so far I didn't notice any problem). Is it a possible cause?

Comment: I don't think so. By killing apps, memory is cleared from RAM, not eMMC.

Comment: Memory = storage space. I guess I typed something wrong. What you say now?

Comment: RAM is volatile memory (that requires electric current to hold data) which running processes use along with CPUs. That's the basics of computing. Hard disks and Flash Memory (SSDs, eMMC, USB sticks, SD cards etc.) are forms of persistent memory (that aren't dependent on electric current). Running processes (including all your apps) have nothing to do whether your persistent memory (eMMC) is completely full or completely empty (more than 90 or 95% full may break apps sometimes). Operating System (Android) kills running processes (apps) to free up RAM for other processes. I hope I made my point.

Comment: If you think freeing up space on your storage resolved your problem of missed / delayed notifications, you can add that as accepted answer for others' benefit.

Comment: Sure. But I'm not sure if this solved the problem. So I wanted to know about it, if you knew something like this.